# Is there a faster algorithm for constructing the adjacency list of this graph?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, complexity-theory

My problem is to find a better algorithm to fill the adjacency list.

specs:

```
G = (V , E ) //the graph
V ={w} //vertex in this case each vertex is an array     
E={⟨u,v⟩| u,v ∈V ∧ u>v} // edge only if u > v
u > v only if  foreach i u̸=v ∧ u[i]≥v[i]. // (u>v and v>w => u>w)
```

my naive code whit complexity **O((v+1)*v/2) ≈ O(n^2)** is

```
private void riempiAdj() {
    for(int i=0;i<nodi.length;i++)
        for(int j=i+1;j<nodi.length;j++)
            if(nodi[i].eMaggiore(nodi[j]))
                nodi[i].adj.inserisci(nodi[j]);     
}
```

`nodi` is the array of vertex

`adj` is the adjacency list

`AdjList.inserisci(Vertex t)` add a vertex t into adjacency list **O(1)**

`Vertex.eMaggiore(Vertex t)` returns true in this > t **O(1)**

exist an algorithm whit complexity of **O(v)** or **O(v*log()v)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worst case, the graph you're trying to build has Θ(|V|<sup>2</sup>) edges in it (the total number of edges is 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + |V|-1 = |V|(|V| - 1) / 2), so any algorithm that explicitly builds the adjacency list for the graph will necessarily have to do Ω(|V|<sup>2</sup>) work in the worst-case simply because that many edges need to be added.

Since there's a nice pattern to the edges here, you could conceivably create some sort of lazily-evaluated adjacency list that only creates the edges when they're needed, though that's a separate question.

Comment: i think Θ(|V|2) edges is not correct because **evrey element ** in the array must be greater or equal to the the same index element of the other array so for ezample if i have n array:
    a1:1,0,0,0,0...,0
    a2:0,1,0,0,0...,0
    a3:0,0,1,0,0...,0
    an:,0,0,0,0...,1
i have 0 edges

Comment: The answer is correct, in the worst case every node is connected to every other.